# How Can I get the timestamp a request was sent from the client?

Tags: python, http, flask

I want to calculate the delay between a client sending a request to my flask api and my flask api receiving the request. Right now I'm trying this:

```
@current_app.before_request
def before_request():
    print(request.date)
```

But I am printing `None`

Flask's documentation states this will work here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin.date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those flask docs are referencing the `Date` header. It will print `None` unless the `Date` header is specified in the request.

The [MDN Docs for header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) show you the format of the header. Send a request with that header and you'll have the information you need.

If you can't control the client sending your requests, I don't think there is a way to achieve what you're looking for.